# how can I detect farsi web pages by tika?

Tags: java, apache, apache-tika, language-detection, farsi

I need a sample code to help me detect farsi language web pages by apache tika toolkit.

```
 LanguageIdentifier identifier = new LanguageIdentifier("فارسی");
        String language = identifier.getLanguage();
```

I have download apache.tika jar files and add them to the classpath. but this code gives error for Farsi language but it works for english.
how can I add Farsi to languageIdentifier package of tika?

Comment: What kind of error? Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: it is surprising but I dont have any error now but the problem is that it detects incorrectly. it return "lt" that means Lithuanian language instead of Persian(farsi) language

Comment: my question is how tika detects languages? with what files? for example if it uses stop words of any language where can I add the stop words of farsi language?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tika doesn't ship with a language profile for the Farsi language yet. As of version 1.0 [27 languages are supported](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tika/trunk/tika-core/src/main/resources/org/apache/tika/language/tika.language.properties?view=markup) out of the box:

```
languages=be,ca,da,de,eo,et,el,en,es,fi,fr,gl,hu,is,it,lt,nl,no,pl,pt,ro,ru,sk,sl,sv,th,uk
```

In your example the input is misdetected as `li`(Lithuanian) with a distance of 0.41, which is above the certainty threshold of 0.022. See the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tika/tika-core/1.0/org/apache/tika/language/LanguageIdentifier.java#LanguageIdentifier.0distance) for more information on the inner works of `LanguageIdentifier`.

The Farsi language ([Persian, ISO 639-1 2-letter code `fa`](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php)) is not recognized by default.
If you want Tika to recognize another language, you have to create a language profile first.

For this the following steps are necessary:

1. Find a text corpus for your language. I found the [Hamshahri Collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamshahri_Corpus). This should be sufficient. Download the corpus or parts of it and create a plain text file out of the XML.
2. Create an ngram file for the language identifier. This can be done using [TikaCLI](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-546):

   `java -jar tika-app-1.0.jar --create-profile=fa -eUTF-8 fa-corpus.txt`
   This will a file called `fa.ngp` which contains the n-grams.
3. Configure Tika so that it recognizes the new language. Either do this programmatically using `LanguageIdentifier.initProfiles()` or put a property file with the name `tika.language.override.properties` into the classpath. Make sure the ngram file is in the classpath as well.

If you now run Tika, it should correctly detect your language.

Update:
Detailed the steps necessary to create a language profile.

Comment: I follow the link but I dont understand how can I create the language profile. can you help me?

Comment: in fact. I ask my question about create language profile in link below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227565/adding-language-profile-to-apache-tika

Comment: after finding enough text corpus, what should I do?

Comment: thank you alot. can you give some sample code on how to use TikaCLI?

Comment: You missed out the final step of contributing the new profile back to Tika! :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/283200/kai-sternad  Looks like '--create-profile' has been dropped in newer version of tika. How does one go abou contributing new profiles?