# how to create language profile in tika for adding other language identification to it?

Tags: apache, apache-tika, language-detection

at first, I tried to detect Farsi language by tika:

[how can I detect farsi web pages by tika?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044916/how-can-i-detect-farsi-web-pages-by-tika/9045385#9045385)

but I understood that tika does not support farsi language and I must create language profile in tika to handle Farsi. but I dont know how to do that. actually I cant understand anything from the following link or other links in google. please help me.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-546

I want to know the steps of adding language profile to tika.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated [my answer on your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044916/how-can-i-detect-farsi-web-pages-by-tika/9045385) with detailed steps on how to add a new language profile to Tika.